# Access variable value from decorator after decorated function executes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

```py
def memoize(fn):
    memory=dict()
    def inner(inpt):
        if not inpt in memory:
            memory[inpt] = fn(inpt)
        return memory[inpt]
    return inner

@memoize
def expected_rounds(picks_to_go):
    #algorithm....
    ans += expected_rounds(new_picks_to_go) #some recursion
    #algorithm....
    return ans
```

How to access (and even print) variable `memory` in `memoize` decorator after function will successfully end execution and return answer?

Comment: Given how you've currently implemented it, it's only in the *closure*. If you set e.g. `inner._memory = memory` before `return inner`, you could then access `expected_rounds._memory`.

Answer (score 0):

my idea that I created after posting question it uses class but I would like to stay with function decorator:

```py
#class callable that can be used as decorator
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self):
        self.memory = {}
#         self.fn = None

    def set_fn(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        return self # this line is important

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.memo:
            self.memory[args] = self.fn(*args)
        return self.memory[args]

memo1 = Memoize()

@memo1.set_fn
def expected_rounds(picks_to_go):
    #something
    return ans

expected_rounds(some_input)

memo1.memory # <- access to memory possible
```